# How to do face recognition using euclidean distance in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition, euclidean-distance

I have a project where I need to include `face recognition` in it. I am referring to this [article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/). This article is using `open-face` to get the face `embeddings` and its saving all the embeddings in a pickle file. Then its passing the face embeddings data to `support vector machine` which generates another pickle file. This file is later used to recognize and predict the face.

This has been working and is giving me more than 80% accuracy. But this article has not explained on how to calculate `euclidean distance`. This I needed for my own research work.

I can easily calculate `euclidean distance` between the face embedding of test image and face embeddings present in pickle file but I am not able to understand how to set the threshold value so that any distance more than that will be tagged as `unknown`.

Can anyone please point me to some article where this has been explained and I can follow up from there. I have tried searching many articles but didnt get much results on this. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build 2 ( normal ) distributions.

1. distances between same person's faces
2. distances between different faces

Intersection of these distributuins will be the threshold.

Small illustration:
[image]

Comment: Blue color in your graph represent personA and red color in the graph represent personB. Is that correct.?

Comment: No, left is represent that A=B, right represent A!=B. So if you need compare 2 persons, you need compare the euclidian dist's with the threshold.

Comment: So you mean, this is basically the result of our face recognition, which can be like 5 images didnt match and 10 images match, and this blue represent those 5 images distance and red represent 10 images distance. Am I correct this time.?

Comment: Yes, left is distribution of distances for known  same persons images, and the right is distribution for different ones distances.  These distributions are generated by computing the distance for set of known pairs from training dataset.

Comment: Or better validation dataset, not training.

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you have any links to article where I can see some useful code to start with.

Comment: Check here for instance: https://github.com/foamliu/InsightFace-v2/blob/master/lfw_eval.py  There used angular metric, but there is no much difference. BTW the image generated using thet code.

Comment: Some theory: https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/basics-of-bayesian-decision-theory